# Problem with PNG images in C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics, png

Working in Visual Studio 2008. I'm trying to draw on a PNG image and save that image again.

I do the following:

```
private Image img = Image.FromFile("file.png");
private Graphics newGraphics;
```

And in the constructor:

```
newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

Building the solution gives no errors. When I try to run it, I get this:

> A Graphics object cannot be created
>   from an image that has an indexed
>   pixel format.

I don't have much experience with using images in C#. What does this mean and how can I remedy this?

EDIT: through debugging, Visual Studio tells me that the image has a **`format8bppindexed`** Pixel Format.

So if I can't use the Graphics class, what do I use?

EDIT2: After reading [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3467d053-2373-4777-bfa6-75d8517be600), I think it's safe to assume that I better stick to JPG files when working with GDI+, no?

EDIT3: my using-statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: Any luck with this method? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rrraman/graphicsObject08232007102733AM/graphicsObject.aspx

Comment: I use PNG files with the Graphics object all the time. Post a link to the PNG file you're using, and we'll see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Internally GDI works with Bitmaps, JPG is compressed and not really great having a compressed image for working with the raw data.  Your image is 8bppIndexed, this is a Bitmap format where the colours are stored in the palette not the pixel data.  The Graphics objects can't modify the pixel values directly, as that won't change it.  You need to convert it to 24bppRGB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without a better PNG library that supports indexed PNGs you're out of luck trying to draw to that image since evidently the GDI+ graphics object doesn't support indexed images.

If you don't need to use indexed PNGs you could trap that error and convert your input to regular RGB PNGs using a 3rd party utility.

edit:

I did find this link http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2008/02/c-indexed-pixel-problem.html that gives a method to draw on your image, however it won't affect the original, just a copy you can Save() if you require.

In case the link goes down:

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Fci-h.jpg",true);
Bitmap tmp=new Bitmap (bm.Width ,bm.Height );
Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);
grPhoto.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width , tmp.Height ), 0, 0, tmp.Width , tmp.Height , GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: GDI+ doesn't support creating a graphics context from them which has the same effect for the OP.  Anyways, here's a decent link for a workaround solution:
http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2008/02/c-indexed-pixel-problem.html

Comment: That blogpost did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot create a graphics from an indexed image format (PNG, GIF,...).
You should use a Bitmap (file or convert your image to a bitmap).

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("file.png");
img = new Bitmap(img);
newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't have a the needed "using" statement, but Visual Studio doesn't recognise that function.

Comment: As per the docs, this won't work with an Indexed image http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx

Comment: badbod99 > You missed the 
img = new Bitmap(img);

Comment: It's within the System.Drawing namespace.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx