# C# watermarking not working for .gif and .tif images

Tags: c#, watermark

I'm trying to watermark images with a .png image
my .jpg and .png images are getting watermarked properly but .tif and .gif images give error.

I'm doing it in c#.
and i get this errror :

> {"A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an
>   indexed pixel format. at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Image
>   image)   at Watermarking.test_image_watermak.button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) "}

My code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(img, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    image = Image.FromStream(fs);

                    int newWaterWidth = (int)((float)image.Width * .30);


                    int newWaterHeight = (newWaterWidth * watermarkImage.Height) / watermarkImage.Width;

                    Bitmap resizedWaterm = new Bitmap(newWaterWidth, newWaterHeight);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)resizedWaterm);

                    g.DrawImage(watermarkImage, 0, 0, newWaterWidth, newWaterHeight);

                    ***Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);*** //error at this line

                    TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush((Image)resizedWaterm);
                    int x = (image.Width / 2 - resizedWaterm.Width / 2);

                    int y = (image.Height / 2 - resizedWaterm.Height / 2);

                    watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);

                    imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(resizedWaterm.Width + 1, resizedWaterm.Height)));
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(img);

                    image.Save(outputFolder + "\\" + filename);
```

Is there anything different that you need to do for these types of images ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with PNG images in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625170/problem-with-png-images-in-c-sharp)

Comment: i'll try that but i don't think that'l work....
thank you @codecaster

Comment: You need to show what you have tried anyway. That question shows the same error and also a solution for it: drawing on a copy of the image (`img = new Bitmap(img);
newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);`). You would have found that question if you searched the web on your error message, which is expected of you. So please try to understand what is being told in that question and answer, then if it still doesn't work update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: i'm sorry but that solution doesnt work.. im using filestream and using that solution gives error

Comment: That's what I mean by _"try to understand what is being told in that question and answer"_. It doesn't matter you're using a filestream, as `Image.FromStream()` returns an `Image`. You can then create a [`new Bitmap(Image)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx) and create a `Graphics` object to draw on that bitmap. Just as explained in the question and answer I linked.

Comment: @CodeCaster i did create a new bitmap and then a graphics object..
i read ur suggested post, understood it and then applied soultion accordingly.. but im getting error for .tif & .gif images.

Comment: _"then if it still doesn't work update your question with what you have tried."_ - then do that and show the error.

Answer (score 0):

"A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format." tells for itself.
GIF images are palette-based, your TIFF image seems to be indexed too (while there are full-color TIFFs).

Comment: yeah i guess that's wat is happening..
any solution ?? @Nickolay Olshevsky

Comment: You can use Image.Save method to convert it to png/jpg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx and add watermark after this.

Comment: the thing is its not getting loaded in graphics object... and i want to keep the file extension the same..